# Действия в коде повторяются сами по себе, если введена неверная капча

Tags: python, selenium

Есть скрипт который в цикле переходит по ссылкам и вводит капчу.
Если капча введена верно, то все ок.
Если неверно, то страница начинает зациклено перезагружаться и вводить тот же неверный ответ.
Причем это происходит именно в режиме запуска, если запускаю дебаг и прохожусь построчно, то все ок.

Прилаживаю часть кода: https://pastebin.com/Hh53U0wz

Повторяется именно эта строчка:

```
else:
    print(f"В: {captcha_text}", f'П: {captcha_placeholder}', f'О: {captcha_answer}')
    self.send_answer_captcha(captcha_answer)
```

Что видно по выводу в консоль, т.к идет этот принт и 2 принта с метода:
[Вывод в консоль](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfuTO.png)

Буду рад любой помощи, большое спасибо.